# VBA: Insert SQL Server BLOB (image) data to a Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this Java code that retrieves the BLOB (image) data in SQL Server 2008 and pass it to a macro in word.

But my problem is that I don't know how convert the passed data *SQL Server BLOB (image)* into an image to be inserted in the word document.

Is there a way for me to do this? And are there any tutorials regarding this case for me to play with? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Save it to a temp file and pass the path to the Word macro.

Comment: ohhh, I'll consider this. Thank you Tim.